# How to remove upload button in nicEdit text editor

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, nicedit

I am fine with all the buttons of nicedit for my website. But i would like to remove upload button of the editor in one of my website. I got an option of ppulating button list, but i am searching for setting like:

**fullPanel: true, hideButton: 'upload'**

Comment: why don't you hide it from the property? ..`visible=false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin does not seem to have a `hideButton` option.
You can either have the full button list, or explicitely choose the buttons to show with the `buttonList` option.

[Documentation](http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/515/Configuration%20Options)

I was thinking that maybe you could hide it using CSS but the plugin does add any class or IDs to the buttons so it would make it pretty unreliable to target.

Comment: hm.. after checking the documentation, I also came to notice the only way we are doing is the correct one. It needs to add one more option RemoveButtons

Answer (score 4):

Just put buttons that you need.

```
new nicEditor({buttonList : ['fontSize','bold','italic','underline','strikeThrough','subscript','superscript','html','image']}).panelInstance('area1');
```

Comment: remember to set full panel to false "new nicEditor({fullPanel : false, buttonList..."

Answer (score 0):

You can go to nicEdit.js try to find .. buttonList .. at there you can see button list.
Delete the ,upload

Answer (score 0):

I've been extending and fixing the nicEdit plugin (added easy YouTube embedding and DragNDropz https://dragndropz.com image upload support) quite a bit lately, and I added an ignore buttons option as well to easily ignore specific buttons.

Source and updated version is here:

https://dev.x-null.net/own3mall/nic-edit/tree/yt-videos

Example of how to use it:

```
myNicEditor = new nicEditor({fullPanel : true, buttonIgnoreList: new Array('upload', 'youtube')}).panelInstance('go_nicedit',{hasPanel : true});
```